Keyboard getting inconsistent latency spikes that last ~5s
I couldn't explain this well in the title, so I'll do it a little more in-depth here:
Every minute or so, my (windows 11) PC makes the device disconnect sound and my keyboard gets a huge latency spike. The latency probably goes up to about 1000ms. Then, after ~5s, my PC makes the device connect sound and the latency goes back to normal. I have tried many tutorials that claim to fix keyboards disconnecting. This only happens with keyboards, no other types of devices. Here are all of the things that I have tried:

Changing USB ports (even used a hub, so the ports aren't dirty or anything)
Changing keyboards
Forgetting the device
Reinstalling drivers
Running the keyboard troubleshooter
Changing power saving options
maybe more idk

I don't know if these matter, but here are my specs:
CPU: Intel i5-12400F
GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 1660 Super
RAM: Corsair Vengeance LPX 16Gb (2 8gb)
Motherboard: MSI Pro B760M-P DDR4
Don't think any other specs would matter.

I'm missing a very important spec. What keyboard and is it wired or wireless? And in case wireless, does it has its own dongle or bluetooth through OS?

The keyboards are the redragon k552 and logitech mk120, and they are both wired.

Have you tried reseating/replugging any PC components? I once experienced something similar and that helped. You could also try booting from a Linux live USB to see if the problem is OS specific, to help narrow it down.

I will try to rework the connection between my components, but which ones do you think would be causing the issue?

Didn't work ;( Also, how do you get a linux live usb?
